# How to add module to Play! Framework 2.6 with custom application loader

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I have a module in my Play 2.6.11 app which I want to enable like

```
play.modules.enabled  += "my.Module"
```

This works great if I use the default (Guice) application loader provide by Play. However, I also need my custom application loader like

```
play.application.loader = MyApplicationLoader
```

Together, `my.Module` is not instantiated.

Does anyone has experience using these 2 together? I have a hard time finding relevant documentation about this as well.

The [Play module docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaPlayModules) don't mention custom application loaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this the following way

Custom loader

```
import play.api.{Application, ApplicationLoader}

class CustomLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): Application =
    new CustomModule(context).application
}
```

In `application.conf`

```
application.loader = CustomLoader
```

`CustomModule` can load all other components.